# how to restore bookmarks folder in ubuntu 12.04 LTS from google chrome

Tags: 12.04, restore, bookmarks

I accidentally deleted some folders with bookmarks from bookmark manager in google chrome. running in Ubuntu 12.04. Can someone else tell me how restore them?

Comment: Do you sync chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this, after deleting my bookmarks off a public-y computer after logging out (but not 'logged out' enough). Later I started my main computer and *POOF* the bookmarks vanished.

1. Create at least one more copy of your good bookmarks on a good computer (use `Bookmarks.bak` even). Don't restoring it yet - if you deleted them from ANOTHER computer, they'll just get trashed again.
2. Open Chrome, go to Settings → People → Sync → disable 'Synch Bookmarks' (maybe disable 'synch all' first)
3. Disable internet access (unplug cable, disable WiFi, whatever)
4. Copy your good bookmarks copy to `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks`
5. Start Chrome
6. go to `https://www.google.com/bookmarks/` [how did I manage this with networking off? either it worked, or I've missed a step]
7. 'Export Bookmarks' (LHS panel) somewhere
8. Close Chrome
9. Re-enable networking, re-start Chrome, Re-enable Bookmark synch, Watch your bookmarks disappear again
10. Bookmarks → Import bookmarks and settings → (change from Mozilla Firefox to Bookmarks HTML file) → Choose file → point to file you saved earlier
11. Enjoy your old bookmarks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Bookmarks` or `Bookmarks.bak` file that still holds the information you want, but are unable to make chrome add those bookmarks again, I found this really helpful online tool to convert those json files to an HTML file that you can then just import via the top-right corner in the `chrome://bookmarks/` screen:

https://rongjiecomputer.github.io/chrome/bookmark-recovery/#linux

Answer (score 0):

You can only restore what you have backed up. Did you create a backup in any way? Chrome stores its configuration in `~/.config/google-chrome` if you restore this folder your bookmarks should be back.

If you are lucky you find the file ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak still containing your folder. Move this file to a safe location, stop your browser, move it back to `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks` start your browser and keep your fingers crossed.

If you do not have a backup, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0):

Just perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in `chrome://bookmarks`.